# Angular - changes to directive controller's scope aren't reflected in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-controller

Changes to my scope variable `foo` are getting updated in the html.  When that value is change inside the scope of a directive's controller, it isn't updating in the html.

What do I need to do to make it update?

I have a simple [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/OqZDH9T6igqUI1laGfDe?p=preview):

> app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = 99;

  $scope.changeValue = function() {
    $scope.foo = $scope.foo + 1;
  }
});

app.directive('d1', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      theFoo: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'd1.html',
    controller: 'd1Ctrl',
  }
});

app.controller('d1Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = $scope.theFoo;
});
```

> d1.html

```
<div>
  <p>The value of foo is '{{theFoo}}'.</p>
  <p>The value of test is '{{test}}'.</p>
</div>
```

> inside index.html

```
<d1 the-foo='foo'>
</d1>

<button ng-click='changeValue()'>change value</button>
```

So in summary, `{{theFoo}}` is updating, but `{{test}}` isn't.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `$scope.foo` value is a primitive.

In the directive controller you only assign `$scope.test` once when controller initializes. Primitives have no inheritance the way objects do so there is nothing that would change `$scope.test` after that initial assignment

If you used an object instead to pass in ... inheritance would be in effect and you would see changes...otherwise you would need to watch `$scope.theFoo` and do updates to `$scope.test` yourself

Comment: This is one of the issues I have with Angular.  Although using *controller-as* seems to avoid most of these headaches because it is treated as the non-primitive, I still don't like how we have to rethink our way around primitive value updates

Comment: @jusopi whole issue disappears if you follow best practices and use objects instead of primitives. I rarely use  $watch in my code and make sure that I am using object properties in view rather than primitives

Comment: sorry but to say the whole issue disappears is incorrect. Unless he changes the internal workings of the directive to pull the test value from the non-primitive bound value, `test` is still not updated.   http://plnkr.co/edit/bRrQ9z4oBYrdBCLwbOjP?p=preview

Comment: @jusopi but that's still passing a primitive not an object

Comment: Then his directive will have to have some knowledge of the non-primitive getting passed in.  I think that's bad design.  I'd rather encumber the performance penalty of the $watch statement than to have the directive "know" about an object's properties.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have in your controller only initializes to that value if it is indeed set at the time the controller is linked.  Any subsequent changes are not going to work.

If you want to bind any subsequent changes, then you need to set a $watch statement either in your controller or a link function.

```
$scope.$watch( 'theFoo', function(val){ $scope.test = val; })
```

updated plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/eWoPutIJrwxZj9XJu6QG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

here you have isolated the scope of the directive, so `test` is not visible to the `d1.html`, if you need to change `test` along with the `theFoo`  you must first make it visible to the directive by

```
app.directive('d1', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      theFoo: '=',
      test : '=' //getting test as well
    },
    templateUrl: 'd1.html',
    controller: 'd1Ctrl',
  }
});
```

and in index.html you should pass the value to the test by
`<d1 the-foo='foo' test='foo'></d1>`

in the above code your controller is not much of a  use , code will work  fine even without this part `controller: 'd1Ctrl'`.
with this example you dont have to use `$watch`.

Comment: It's a simplified example to demonstrate my problem - `test` is defined in the directive controller's scope - so it must be visible.  Plus it gets the value initially, it doesn't update though.